# Page Numbering for All Pages (Top Right-Hand Side)

Tags: header-footer, numbering, titles, page-numbering

I am writing my thesis using the `fancyhdr` package and the `report` document class.  My university requires me to number each page (including the title page) in the top right-hand side.  My current code does not put page numbers on the title page and numbers the first page of the thesis in the bottom center part of the page.

Can someone help me fix this?  I have no clue how to stop Latex from doing this.

Comment: You mean the `fancyhdr` package, most likely. By default titlepages use the `empty` page style and have no page numbers

Comment: Thanks for the insight on this.  I did not know.  Is there another package that I can use instead?

Comment: It is possible to use `fancyhdr` package, but the `empty` page style must be kicked out of the titlepage. the `titling` package allows for designing other page styles. On the other hand: A title page is an ordinary page effectively, there is no need to use `\maketitle` -- you can design as you like...

Comment: Are you just using plain `report` class or a custom class?

Comment: Yes, I am using the REPORT class.

Comment: @MarvinLoiseau try to use the "\`" -> the key used in latex for begin quotes next to `1` and over `tab` ... this will place the lowercase "report" inside an "environment" (like this: `report` )that will make as understand that you used a "special word" ... may be it is a matter of habit but the uppercase are used to create a somehow "negative atmosphere"  in forums-communities and in SE too (that is nothing of these two as somebody talked me :P )..

Answer (score 3):

The standard classes make the page style of the title page `empty` and the page style of the first pages of chapters `plain`. The simplest solution is to patch the `{titlepage}` environment and the `\chapter` macro to use the `fancy` pagestyle, and define that style to put page numbers in the top right corner.  I've used the `etoolbox` package to do that.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{}
\chead{}
\rhead{\thepage}
\cfoot{}
\lfoot{}
\rfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrule}{}
\title{The title}
\author{An Author}
\patchcmd{\titlepage}{empty}{fancy}{}{}
\patchcmd{\chapter}{plain}{fancy}{}{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\setcounter{page}{2} % needed if pages are to be continuously numbered
\chapter{A chapter}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: The funny thing is that I show your picture and was looking for the page number... Thought that was lower than the screenshot :P (+1)

Comment: Wow!  That worked perfectly... THANK YOU!!!!

Answer (score 1):

A silly hack, of these I am used too, but sure will cause problems if for example you use a author with optional argument, or a short title of the report or whatever. But if not is an easy fix without changes in the body or usage of packages:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}


%
\let\oldauthor\author
\let\oldtitle\title
\let\olddate\date
\def\author#1{\xdef\mtheauthor{#1}\oldauthor{#1}}
\def\title#1{\xdef\mthetitle{#1}\oldtitle{#1}}
%\def\date#1{\xdef\mthedate{#1}\olddate{#1}}
\let\oldmaketitle\maketitle
\def\maketitle{\phantom{.}\par\vspace{150pt}{\centering{\LARGE\mthetitle\par}\vspace{25pt}{\large\mtheauthor\par}\vspace{15pt}{\large\today\par}\vfill}\pagebreak}
\let\oldchapter\chapter
\makeatletter
\def\chapter{%
\@ifstar{\@Starred}{\@nonStarred}%
}
\def\@Starred{%
\@ifnextchar[%
{\GenericWarning{}{Warning: A starred section can not have parameters. I am going to ignore them!}\@StarredWith}%
{\@StarredWithout}%
}      
\def\@StarredWith[#1]#2{%
\oldchapter*{#2}%
\thispagestyle{fancy}%
}
\def\@StarredWithout#1{
\oldchapter*{#1}%
\thispagestyle{fancy}%
}
\def\@nonStarred{%
\@ifnextchar[%
{\@nonStarredWith}%
{\@nonStarredWithout}%
}
\def\@nonStarredWith[#1]#2{%
\oldchapter[#1]{#2}%
\thispagestyle{fancy}%
}
\def\@nonStarredWithout#1{%
\oldchapter{#1}%
\thispagestyle{fancy}%
}
\makeatother

\title{Test title}
\author{Me and myself}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents
\chapter{Test chapter}
\section{Test Sec}
\lipsum[2]
\subsection{Test Subsec}
\subsubsection{Test Subsubsec}

\setcounter{section}{32}
\section{Test Sec}
\lipsum[2]
\subsection{Test Subsec}
\subsubsection{Test Subsubsec}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: @AlanMunn Thanks for noticing... Think that fixed but I will read again the post's request... Didn't... Thanks...

Comment: Added another usual hack of mine :P